# Emphasis in Isaiah 50:11

Tags: hebrew, grammar, isaiah, authorial-intent

Does the phrase here translated - "this you shall have of mine hand" - refer to the the previous portion of the verse, or does it refer to the latter portion of the verse?

> Is 50:11 (KJV) Behold, all ye that kindle a fire, that compass yourselves about with sparks: walk in the light of your fire, and in the sparks that ye have kindled. This shall ye have of mine hand; ye shall lie down in sorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Isa 50:11 says this (NASB)

> Behold, all you who kindle a fire, Who encircle yourselves with
> flaming arrows, Walk in the light of your fire And among the flaming
> arrows you have set ablaze. **This you will have from My hand**: You
> will lie down in torment.

The highlighted sentence refers to that which follows; however, "*you shall lie down in torment*" refers back to the earlier part of the verse, "*Who encircle yourselves with flaming arrows, Walk in the light of your fire And among the flaming arrows you have set ablaze*."

Thus, what they receive from the hand of God is the consequence of their own evil deeds.  Thus, Isa 50:11 is an other example of the many places in the Bible where God allows the consequences of sin to recoil upon itself.  See appendix below.

In this case, there appears to be an anticipated contrast between the wicked's own light and "the light of the world" namely, Messiah Jesus as per John 8:12

> Again Jesus spoke to them, saying, “I am the light of the world.
> Whoever follows me will not walk in darkness, but will have the light
> of life.”

In commenting on Isa 50:11, Ellicott says:

> (11) All ye that kindle a fire.—The words obviously point to any human
> substitute for the Divine light, and thus include the two meanings
> which commentators have given them: (1) Man’s fiery wrath, that
> worketh not the righteousness of God; and (2) man’s attempt to rest in
> earthly comforts or enjoyments instead of in the light and joy that
> comes from God.

The Cambridge commentary is more succinct

> **walk in the light &c**. Rather: walk into the flame of your fire &c. Their mischievous designs shall recoil on themselves (Psalm 7:15 f.).

Thus, most translations render the verse something close to the ESV:

> Behold, all you who kindle a fire, who equip yourselves with burning
> torches! Walk by the light of your fire, and by the torches that you
> have kindled! This you have from my hand: you shall lie down in
> torment.

That is, the torment suffered by the wicked lighting their own path (rather than the divine light) is the torment of their own making that God permits them to suffer; God allows the consequences to reap their evil consequences on the perpetrators.

**APPENDIX - Sin contains the seeds of its own destruction.**

God allows sin and evil to reap its own consequences and cause its own downfall.

- Job 5:13 - He catches the wise in their own craftiness, and the schemes of the wily are brought to a quick end.
- Ps 5:10 - Declare them guilty, O God; let them fall by their own devices. Drive them out for their many transgressions, for they have rebelled against You.
- Ps 7:15 - He has dug a hole and hollowed it out; he has fallen into a pit of his own making.
- Ps 9:16 - The LORD is known by the justice He brings; the wicked are ensnared by the work of their hands.
- Ps 69:22 - Let their own table before them become a snare; and when they are at peace, let it become a trap.
- Ps 141:10 - Let the wicked fall into their own nets, while I pass by in safety.
- Prov 5:22 - The iniquities of a wicked man entrap him; the cords of his sin entangle him.
- Prov 11:6 - The righteousness of the upright delivers them, but the faithless are trapped by their own desires.
- Prov 12:13 - An evil man is trapped by his rebellious speech, but a righteous man escapes from trouble.
- Prov 28:10 - He who leads the upright along the path of evil will fall into his own pit, but the blameless will inherit what is good.
- Hos 11:6 – A sword will flash through their cities; it will destroy the bars of their gates and consume them in their own plans.
- Job 5:13 - He catches the wise in their own craftiness, and the schemes of the wily are brought to a quick end.

Answer (score 0):

**Does the phrase - "This shall ye have of Mine Hand" from Isaiah 50:11 [KJV] - refer to the the previous portion ["in the Sparks that ye have kindled"], or does it refer to the latter portion ["ye shall lie down in sorrow"] ?**

**Isaiah 50:11 [KJV]** :

> Behold, all ye that kindle a fire, that compass yourselves about with sparks: walk in the light of your fire, and in the sparks that ye have kindled. This shall ye have of mine hand ; ye shall lie down in sorrow.

- Readers should examine both the original Ivri (Hebrew) phrase "Mi-Yadi Hayetah Zot La-kem" (**מִיָּדִי֙ הָֽיְתָה־זֹּ֣את לָכֶ֔ם**) along with the English KJV translation "**from My hand has this come to you**" in [Isaiah 50:11] :

The prophet Yeshayahu states in **Isaiah 50:11** [MT] :
"Behold all of you who kindle fire, who give power to flames; go in the flame of your fire, and in-Awakening you have kindled; **from My hand has this come to you**, in grief you shall lie down. (הֵ֧ן כֻּלְּכֶ֛ם קֹ֥דְחֵי אֵ֖שׁ מְאַזְּרֵ֣י זִיק֑וֹת לְכ֣וּ | בְּא֣וּר אֶשְׁכֶ֗ם וּבְזִיקוֹת֙ בִּֽעַרְתֶּ֔ם **מִיָּדִי֙ הָֽיְתָה־זֹּ֣את לָכֶ֔ם** לְמַֽעֲצֵבָ֖ה תִּשְׁכָּבֽוּן )

Now analyze the Ivri (Hebrew) phrase : "Mi-Yadi Hayetah Zot La-kem" (**מִיָּדִי֙ הָֽיְתָה־זֹּ֣את לָכֶ֔ם**), by comparing the Ivri words [MT] translated into [KJV] **"This shall ye have of Mine Hand"** :

- Mi-Yadi (מִיָּדִי֙) / From-Hand-My = "of My Hand".
- Hayetah (הָֽיְתָה) / Have-Shall = "shall have".
- Zot (זֹּ֣את) / This = "This".
- La-Kem (לָכֶ֔ם) / To-You = "ye".

> The phrase : "This shall ye have of Mine Hand" [KJV] relates to **"in the Awakening" (בִּֽעַרְתֶּ֔ם)** in the previous portion : **"in the Sparks** that ye have kindled" [KJV] .

The Ivri word "Awakening" (עַרְתֶּ֔ם) is a gerund phrase relating to actions of the Living. **Life (Awakening) comes from the Hand of God.**

Reference Hebrew past tense conjugation of "Aretem" (עַרְתֶּ֔ם) / "Artem" : https://www.pealim.com/dict/2777-laur/#h-PERF-2mp

Answer (score 0):

Isaiah 50:11
New International Version

> But now, all you who light fires and provide yourselves with flaming torches, go, walk in the light of your fires and of the torches you have set ablaze. **This** is what you shall receive from my **hand:** You will lie down in torment.

NIV added the colon to indicate that "This" refers to the latter portion of the verse.

At https://biblehub.com/isaiah/50-11.htm 19 out of 25 versions use the colon.

With or without the semicolon, in any case, it refers ambiguously to both portions of the verse.
With the semicolon, more emphasis is placed on the latter portion.